# Distributed transaction with Azure cosmos and blob storage

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage

We are planning to upload some files in blob and data in Cosmos Db in a single transaction

Is it possible to implement a distributed transaction between Azure Cosmos DB and Azure blob storage? If any of the operations fail then other operations should also be reverted.

If not possible then is there any ideal way to implement this feature through any Azure component?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Yes it helps thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i know,no such transactional mechanism across multiple azure components(if yes,just for sql database maybe).

My idea:

1.Use Azure Function,please see this case:[Transactions in Azure Functions with multiple outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49598746/transactions-in-azure-functions-with-multiple-outputs). You could follow the workaround mentioned by @Mikhail Shilkov,using Service Bus. Some details in this [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/transactional-messaging-with-azure-functions-and-service-bus).

2.Implement try-catch programatically by yourself.Include all of your business in one try-catch scope,if you catch any exception,then do the delete action if the data already exists.