# How to implement transaction in Azure Function?

Tags: transactions, azure-functions, dynamics-365

How to keep multiple actions in one transaction? anyone is failed, I want to roll back the whole operation.
e.g.
Action 1 is to write a record to Azure Table.
Action 2 is to write a record to D365.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. In its current form, this question is not a great fit for SO. Please refer to [ask] and show us what you tried and what didn't work. On-topic: does this answer your question? [Transactions in Azure Functions with multiple outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49598746/transactions-in-azure-functions-with-multiple-outputs)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Although the question is similar, this didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at durable functions?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-error-handling?tabs=csharp

Any exceptions are marshaled back to to the orchestrator so you will need to catch and handle each type for failure and "roll back" the completed actions yourself.

There is the idea of a transaction in Dynamics, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/org-service/use-executetransaction

It will roll back ONLY what occurred during that transaction and ONLY in Dynamics.
Its not really recommended, generally MS recommends that we send each request to the API as single requests, and a ExecuteTransaction Request locks the records in the transaction, so likely to have performance impact.